# Static, permanent labels on each line in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a line chart in chart.js.

It is working perfectly, except that instead of a legend, I'd like to label each line, once, with the value it represents.

Here is my data:

```
data: {
            labels: ["5/8/2015", "1/15/2016", "4/22/2016"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "Clinton",
                data: [37, 31, 36],
                lineTension: 0,
                fill: false,
                borderColor: "blue",
                backgroundColor: "blue",
            }, {
                label: "Trump",
                data: [NaN, 16, 23],
                lineTension: 0,
                fill: false,
                borderColor: "red",
                backgroundColor: "red",
            }, {
                label: "Sanders",
                data: [16, 27, 18],
                lineTension: 0,
                fill: false,
                borderColor: "green",
                backgroundColor: "green",
            }, {
                label: "Other named Republicans",
                data: [41, 23, 17],
                lineTension: 0,
                fill: false,
                borderColor: "pink",
                backgroundColor: "pink",
            }, {
                label: "Other/None",
                data: [5, 3, 6],
                lineTension: 0,
                fill: false,
                borderColor: "grey",
                backgroundColor: "grey",
            }]
        },
```

I don't see a way to put the text "Other/None," for example, on the fifth line without asking for user interaction (hover).

Any ideas?

Comment: UPDATE: I can label each point in the data by messing with the animation function: Chart.helpers.each(this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                                var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                                Chart.helpers.each(meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
                                    ctx.fillText(dataset.label, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 10.5);
                                }),this)
                            }),this);... Trying to get each line labeled no more than once

Comment: I don't get what you actually want to do .. Can you edit your question, and add an image of what you want and a playground to work with (for instance [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)), with the code you currently have ?